# working with multi language data (translations) in db using django models

Tags: python, django, django-models, internationalization

I'm using Python 3.9 with Django 4.1 and I want to store data in my database in 3 languages, English, French and Hebrew.

currently I work on addresses so for country, city and street i have columns `name_en`, `name_fr` and `name_he`.

I have `country`, `city` and `street` tables, and also relation tables `CountryCity` that contains country id and city id and `CountryCityStreet` that contains `countryCityId` and `streetId`.

i can get the current used language using `translation.get_language()` and i can take only the first 2 characters to get the desired result (en, fr or he).

so I created a service function to get the first characters:

```
def get_2l_lang():
    lang = translation.get_language()
    return lang[0:lang.find("-")]
```

and I created the models for that:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Countries"
    name_en = models.CharField(unique=True, verbose_name="English Country Name", max_length=100)
    name_fr = models.CharField(unique=True, verbose_name="French Country Name", max_length=100)
    name_he = models.CharField(unique=True, verbose_name="Hebrew Country Name", max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return getattr(self, 'name_' + get_2l_lang())


class City(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Cities"
    name_en = models.CharField(unique=True, verbose_name="English City Name", max_length=100)
    name_fr = models.CharField(unique=True, verbose_name="French City Name", max_length=100)
    name_he = models.CharField(unique=True, verbose_name="Hebrew City Name", max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return getattr(self, 'name_' + get_2l_lang())


class Street(models.Model):
    name_en = models.CharField(unique=True, verbose_name="English Street Name", max_length=100)
    name_fr = models.CharField(unique=True, verbose_name="French Street Name", max_length=100)
    name_he = models.CharField(unique=True, verbose_name="Hebrew Street Name", max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return getattr(self, 'name_' + get_2l_lang())


class CountryCity(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('country', 'city',)

    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Country')
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='City')

    def __str__(self):
        return getattr(self.country, 'name_' + get_2l_lang()) + ', ' + \
               getattr(self.city, 'name_' + get_2l_lang())


class CountryCityStreet(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('countryCity', 'street',)
    countryCity = models.ForeignKey(CountryCity, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Country & City')
    street = models.ForeignKey(Street, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Street')

    def __str__(self):
        return getattr(self.countryCity.country, 'name_' + get_2l_lang()) + ', ' + \
               getattr(self.countryCity.city, 'name_' + get_2l_lang()) + ', ' + \
               getattr(self.street, 'name_' + get_2l_lang())
```

so far so good.

I'm having problems when I want to display it based on language on the admin page,
first.. i couldn't really find a way to switch languages in the admin, but still lets say we're using the system's configured locale.

I registered for admin to show the `CountryCityStreet` model, it has a foreign key for Country and City, and a anther one for street. in order to display it properly i created this Admin Model:

```
class CountryCityStreetAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('get_country', 'get_city', 'street')

    @admin.display(description='Country', ordering='countryCity__country__name_en')
    def get_country(self, obj):
        return getattr(obj.countryCity.country, 'name_' + get_2l_lang())

    @admin.display(description='City', ordering='countryCity__city__name_en')
    def get_city(self, obj):
        return getattr(obj.countryCity.city, 'name_' + get_2l_lang())
```

now here in `ordering` i can't make it dynamic based on the `get_2l_lang()` function.
when I read the django documentation about translation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/translation/ but I couldn't find anything about storing data in different languages.

I tried to google for other packages and I found `django-hvad` which looks amazing and exactly suites my needs but it's very old and tested on `django 1.9.2` so I can't use it.

so how can I resolve it? how can i make django models aware of different languages in the DB?

thanks

Comment: you can use my package django-tof, it is suited on django-hvad, django-parler and django-model-translation. All what you do - is a django-model-translation. DMT add fields (something_lang) himself, and your code can be better with that.